# How to reference Terraform module output value as a input value to another module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

everyone!
I'm using Terraform v1.2.6 with aws provider v4.24.0.
Unfortunately, I'm stuck in referencing value of module output from another module.

My VPC module is generate output value for subnet's id which provisioned in 3 AZs as list type.

So, I'd like to use this value for count variable to provision number of ENI resources.
But when I assigned it to a variable and change it to a count variable using length() function, count variable is always 0.
This is my problem.

Below is the some code snippet for my Terraform code.

```
module "vpc" {

  # Relative path references
  source = "sre-iac-modules/network/vpc"

  region_id = "${var.region_id}"
  env = "${var.env}"
  service_code = "${var.service_code}"
  
  common_tag = {
      CreatedBy = "${var.common_tag.CreatedBy}",
      PeriodFrom = "${var.common_tag.PeriodFrom}",
      PeriodTo = "${var.common_tag.PeriodTo}",
      CostCenter = "${var.common_tag.CostCenter}",
      Project = "${var.common_tag.Project}"
  }


  vpc = {
      cidr_block = "${var.vpc.cidr_block}", 
      protected_subnet_a_cidr = "${var.vpc.protected_subnet_a_cidr}", 
      protected_subnet_b_cidr = "${var.vpc.protected_subnet_b_cidr}" 
      protected_subnet_c_cidr = "${var.vpc.protected_subnet_c_cidr}",
      tgw_subnet_a_cidr = "${var.vpc.tgw_subnet_a_cidr}",
      tgw_subnet_b_cidr = "${var.vpc.tgw_subnet_b_cidr}",
      tgw_subnet_c_cidr = "${var.vpc.tgw_subnet_c_cidr}",
      workload_subnet_a_cidr = "${var.vpc.workload_subnet_a_cidr}", 
      workload_subnet_b_cidr = "${var.vpc.workload_subnet_b_cidr}",
      workload_subnet_c_cidr = "${var.vpc.workload_subnet_c_cidr}", 
      redis_subnet_a_cidr = "${var.vpc.redis_subnet_a_cidr}",
      redis_subnet_b_cidr = "${var.vpc.redis_subnet_b_cidr}",
      redis_subnet_c_cidr = "${var.vpc.redis_subnet_c_cidr}",
      db_subnet_a_cidr = "${var.vpc.db_subnet_a_cidr}",
      db_subnet_b_cidr = "${var.vpc.db_subnet_b_cidr}",
      db_subnet_c_cidr = "${var.vpc.db_subnet_c_cidr}"
  }

}
 


module "nat" {

  # Relative path references
  source = "sre-iac-modules/network/nat"

  region_id = "${var.region_id}"
  env = "${var.env}"
  service_code = "${var.service_code}"

  target_subnets = module.vpc.protected_subnet_ids

  use_managed_nat = true

  depends_on = [module.wink_vpc]
  
 
}
```

Here is the `terraform console` command result.

```
❯ terraform console
> module.vpc
{
  "db_subnet_ids" = [
    "subnet-036b19638fd57d03b",
    "subnet-0989e9ecb9ca2a146",
    "subnet-060db32b53559ecfb",
  ]
  "db_subnet_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-0b3b9b2726675bc9b",
    "rtb-0bba77cb702e60156",
    "rtb-0cce30f5509eb3505",
  ]
  "igw_id" = "igw-01fd17f6c7c98059a"
  "protected_subnet_ids" = [
    "subnet-0ac643148503ed0b5",
    "subnet-039f527ad5e194b01",
    "subnet-07523fedcb50084a3",
  ]
  "protected_subnet_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-0b58c7fc7cd4f8957",
    "rtb-00f85f75400856328",
    "rtb-04663eb73a6a1ff87",
  ]
  "redis_subnet_ids" = [
    "subnet-0dfe56e866f34bc77",
    "subnet-013b60ff183f7192f",
    "subnet-0e51997c9f4548b8a",
  ]
  "redis_subnet_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-03ce16be7d7d5538c",
    "rtb-094ed4728b7f4dff7",
    "rtb-0982f508e27559720",
  ]
  "tgw_subnet_ids" = [
    "subnet-0c1508e5e554213e9",
    "subnet-0c0bd659eddac8e0d",
    "subnet-042d5ee2600ba360e",
  ]
  "tgw_subnet_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-01b5b1374a1cc161e",
    "rtb-0e2d7cdda12ae23f8",
    "rtb-02291036ba98b4b25",
  ]
  "vpc_id" = "vpc-034f718a9ca96bc95"
  "workload_subnet_ids" = [
    "subnet-087dd412ade2d7b79",
    "subnet-01d0466a843c8249b",
    "subnet-048c4a07d0d1a9fbd",
  ]
  "workload_subnet_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-0aafae15877f17c77",
    "rtb-08d65c618047f6007",
    "rtb-05a70c48904e6f7a3",
  ]
}
> module.vpc.protected_subnet_ids
[
  "subnet-0ac643148503ed0b5",
  "subnet-039f527ad5e194b01",
  "subnet-07523fedcb50084a3",
]
>
```

Code snippets in the NAT module..

```
...

resource "aws_eip" "nat-gw-eip" {
  count = length(var.target_subnets)
  vpc      = true
}

....
```

The result of count is always ZERO.

I'm curious why count variable is ZERO.
It should be THREE, because `module.vpc.protected_subnet_ids` had three items in the list.

Please let me know the reason and how to I get the proper result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you do `length(module.vpc.protected_subnet_ids)` in the terraform console?

Comment: Maybe an bug - sometimes it is helpful to remove `.terraform` directory (PLEASE BE PATIENT, I'm not sure, but I think that your `state` file may be saved in this directory, so firstly make a copy of them, or if it's possible just `destroy` infrastructure, then remove `.terraform`, and `apply`. )

Comment: Btw, you can use `for_each = toset(var.target_subnets)` function instead of `count`, it may help too. https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: @MarkoE, Hi. It returns 3.

❯ terraform console
> length(module.vpc.protected_subnet_ids)
3

Comment: @MarkoE 
I've recognized my mistake! I overwrite the variable `target_subnets = []`in the other code snippet. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel 
I've recognized my mistake! I overwrite the variable `target_subnets = []`in the other code snippet. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`Hello, everyone`

It's my mistake.
Finally, I've found my code snippet which assign empty list [] to a variable `target_subnets`.
Thank you for your time.

Anyway, your comments are very helpful to me.

Cheers!